# I need to optimize a mongo collection update

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongo-shell

I need to write a scripte that write a new field to an embedded object in my collection.
lets say my collection name is Proposition and it containes 100000 document and it looks like this :

```
[{
"Id": "1111",
"name":"Name",
"products": [
{
    "productId": "P1",
},{
    "productId": "P2",
}]
}]
```

My goal is to add new a new field called parent for each product :

```
[{
"Id": "1111",
"name":"Name",
"products": [
{
    "productId": "P1",
    **"parent": "parent1"**
},{
    "productId": "P2",
    **"parent": "Parent2"**
}]
}]
```

the parent field i need to get it from another collection called Products that looks like this

```
[{
   "productId": "P1",
   "parent": "parent1"
},
{
    "productId": "P2",
    "parent": "Parent2"
}]
```

so the script needs to get the productId and parent related to it from the Product collection then update the proposition collection that contain the product by adding the parent field.

the script i did for know :

```
db.Products.find()
.toArray()
.forEach(function(product){
        updateWithParentID(product.productId,product.parent)
   })
function updateWithParentID(prosuctId,parent){
db.Propositions.updateOne(
    {'products.productId':prosuctId},
    {$set:{"products.$.parent":parent}})
}
```

its working but unfortunately it takes so many time, so im wondering if there is a better and efficient way to perform this update

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend using bulk write operations for better performance.  Also, for your update, you will need to master the use of arrayFilters for a targeted update for embedding your details into the propositions collection.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the bulkWrite feature.  This will reduce the overall time by removing most of the network latency for round-trips for each update...

```
var batch=[];

db.Products.find().toArray().forEach(function(product) {
    batch.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                "filter": { "products.productId": product.productId },
                "update": { "$set": { "products.$.parent": product.parent } }
            }
        }
    );
});

db.Propositions.bulkWrite(batch, { ordered: false } );
```

As far as accuracy, you did not provide much data to test with.  You may find a need to use arrayFilters.

Comment: thank you so much that was really helpful, the update now takes less than 5s with the bulkWrite, while before it takes 60s